# Writing a whole cmd command in a file that contains different characters,such as ">" or " >>"

Tags: cmd

I want to write this code in a file with file name final.txt:

```
 @echo off dir file1.txt > file2.txt
```

I've tried something like this :

```
"@echo off dir file1.txt > file2.txt"
```

But it only writes

```
"@echo off dir file1.txt > "
```

It doesn't copy the whole command and the inverted commas are copied too.

Answer (score 2):

Some chars have a special meaning and gets executed instead of echoed. `>` is one of them. to echo them, you must "escape" them (with another special char, the caret `^`). Also to execute two commands in one line, you have to separate them with `&` (another one of those special chars). And last not least, to be able to execute the final file, it's extension has to be `.bat` or `.cmd`. And you need another `echo` to echo the `@echo ...`:

```
echo @echo off & dir file1.txt ^> file2.txt > final.bat
```

But `final.bat` would be better readable, if you write every line on its own line:

```
echo @echo off>final.txt
echo dir file1.txt ^>file2.txt >>final.bat
```

(`>>` is used to append to a file instead of overwriting it)

just to mention: `echo` is not the only command that can be quieted with `@`. Shorter code with same effect:

```
echo @dir file1.txt^>file2.txt>>final.bat
```