# How can I create a .txt file on CMD?

Tags: file, cmd

Does someone knows how to **create** a file .txt on **CMD**?,  I need like an order or steps to create it; I see that i need to write {echo "text"> "name".txt} but, i mean the content has not order and sometimes it doesn´t respond correctly.

***Thank you guys***
Well, I know that I was not so clearly 'bout what I wanted to do, and I'm sorry, but, your advices also help me alot, so, Thank u.

Comment: `echo "text" > "name.txt"` Note that the quote is in a different location than your example. What do you mean about the content order?

Comment: I mean for example: {echo color A > Title "Hello World" > Hi.bat}
Is it correctly in the way i did it or am I wrong?

Comment: `echo color A > Title "Hello World" > Hi.bat` doesn't make sense. What do you want to have "afterwards"?

Comment: [possible duplicate[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854904/writing-a-whole-cmd-command-in-a-file-that-contains-different-characters-such-as/31860597#31860597)? (not clear, what you're asking for)

Comment: Please edit the question and put the content of the output file you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a variable with the text first like as follows:

```
set /p txt=Your Text Content; 
echo %txt% > "Location\textfile.txt"
```

EDIT: If you are meaning that the newline doesnt appear all you have to do is the following:

```
echo "FirstLine" > "Location\textfile.txt"
echo. "SecondLine" > "Location\textfile.txt"
```

echo. instead of echo will start a new line.

Comment: Well in some way it helped me but that's not what i wanted haha, I'm trying to make a ".bat" file, but what I want is to create a file in an other thats its running for example
@echo off
cmd /K cd C:\windows
echo color A > Title "Hello World" > Hi.bat

Is the structure okay?

Comment: @F100d do you mean that new lines dont appear? Try my latest post. Also if you could make an edit to your original post that shows what you want the output to look like that would make it more clear.

Comment: `echo` will *always*  "start a new line" (aka. end with a `CRLF` aka linefeed) `echo. something` is the same as `echo  something`. `echo.` is sometimes used to echo an empty line or a possibly empty variable to avoid the `Echo is off` message (better to use `echo/` or even better `echo(` )

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to do this

```
echo "abcdef" > a.txt
echo "12345" >> a.txt
```

the a.txt content will be

> "abcdef"
> "12345"

Answer (score 0):

echo your_text_here > filename.extension

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a binary file:
C:\>type nul > Diff1.vhd